# Why are actions not working when clicked in these Angular Push Notifications?

Tags: angular, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, angular-service-worker

I have implemented everything regarding Push Notifications on my Angular PWA (according to [Angular Service Worker Notifications](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-notifications)) and even **got the notifications to be shown** by the browser, however, when clicking on any button (or on the notification itself), it just closes and the **respective action does not happen**.

---

The versions being used are:

```
"@angular/core": "~11.2.6",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.1102.5",
"@angular/service-worker": "~11.2.6",
```

---

I have tried different notification payloads, and **they all get shown**:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "New Notification!",
    "actions": [
      {"action": "foo", "title": "Open new tab"},
      {"action": "bar", "title": "Focus last"},
      {"action": "baz", "title": "Navigate last"},
      {"action": "qux", "title": "Send request in the background"},
      {"action": "other", "title": "Just notify existing clients"}
    ],
    "data": {
      "onActionClick": {
        "default": {"operation": "openWindow"},
        "foo": {"operation": "openWindow", "url": "/absolute/path"},
        "bar": {"operation": "focusLastFocusedOrOpen", "url": "relative/path"},
        "baz": {"operation": "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen", "url": "https://other.domain.com/"},
        "qux": {"operation": "sendRequest", "url": "https://yet.another.domain.com/"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Push Notification Shown]

---

But, when clicked, nothing happens and the *notificationClicks* fallback Observable gets notified:

[image: Angular Info]

---

What am I missing here?

Thank you very much in advance!